# AdvancedDataGrid and custom sort

Tags: apache-flex

I have a simple flex `dataProvider` like this :

```
private var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {a:"a_1", b:"b_1", hour:"16:00:00"},
            {a:"a_1", b:"b_2", hour:"16:30:00"},
            {a:"a_2", b:"b_2", hour:"17:00:00"},
            {a:"a_3", b:"b_3", hour:"15:00:00"},                
            {a:"a_3", b:"b_3", hour:"16:00:00"}
        ]);
```

I want to use an `AdvancedDataGrid` component to group these data on `a` and `b` fields and sort on hour field. For example here I would like to obtain :

```
 a_3    
  b_3 
   15:00:00
   16:00:00 
 a_1
  b_1 
   16:00:00
  b_2
   16:30:00
 a_2 
  b_2 
   17:00:00
```

But when I add `Object` like `{a:"a_3", b:"b_3", hour:"18:00:00"}` I want this order to become this one :

```
 a_1
  b_1 
   16:00:00
  b_2
   16:30:00
 a_2 
  b_2 
   17:00:00
 a_3    
  b_3 
   15:00:00
   16:00:00 
   18:00:00
```

So one `Object` can modify all `(a_X, b_Y)` pair order in `AdvancedDataGrid` function of its `hour` field.
I think I can not use `compareFunction` because I have to compare many rows, not only one (in my example adding `Object` modifies 3 rows).

I'm not very familiar with `AdvancedDataGrid` so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

PS: actually I use `GroupingCollection2` as `dataProvider` with 2 `GroupingField` on `a` and `b` fields, I don't know if this is the right way...

Comment: Have you considered adding an extra field to each object that you could sort on?  Concatenate max time for the group + a_X + b_Y + time.  So the last three rows would look like 18:00_a3_b3_15:00,  18:00_a3_b3_16:00, 18:00_a3_b3_18:00.

Comment: @Kevin: the key in my case was the hour field. When adding item, this property is initialized with actual time and therefore is located below the "stack" of items so I could develop code on this (see code below). Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Because my `dataField hour` is insertion hour, when I add Item, I'm sure that this item will be placed on the end. My test code is this one :

```
<s:Button label="add" click="generateData(event)" />

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="500" height="800">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="gc" source="{ac}">
            <mx:grouping>
                <mx:Grouping compareFunction="compare">
                    <mx:GroupingField name="a" />
                    <mx:GroupingField name="b" />
                </mx:Grouping>
            </mx:grouping>
        </mx:GroupingCollection2>
    </mx:dataProvider>
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="a" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="b" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="hour" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>


[Bindable]
        private var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([]);

        // Array of "a" property order
        private var order:Array = [];

        protected function generateData(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // test data
            var t:Array = [
                {a:"a_1", b:"b_1", hour:null},
                {a:"a_1", b:"b_1", hour:null},
                {a:"a_1", b:"b_1", hour:null},
                {a:"a_1", b:"b_2", hour:null},
                {a:"a_1", b:"b_2", hour:null},
                {a:"a_2", b:"b_2", hour:null},
                {a:"a_2", b:"b_2", hour:null},
                {a:"a_2", b:"b_2", hour:null},
                {a:"a_2", b:"b_3", hour:null},
                {a:"a_3", b:"b_3", hour:null},
                {a:"a_3", b:"b_4", hour:null},
                {a:"a_3", b:"b_4", hour:null},
                {a:"a_3", b:"b_4", hour:null},
                {a:"a_4", b:"b_5", hour:null},
                {a:"a_5", b:"b_6", hour:null},
                {a:"a_5", b:"b_6", hour:null},              
                            ];  

            // random number of insertions
            var toAddNumber:int = 10 * int(1 + Math.random());  
            var index:int;

            // "a" type added with random insertions
            var aAdded:Array = [];
            var o:Object;

            for(var i:int=0; i<toAddNumber; i++)
            {
                // random item of t added
                index = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (t.length-1 - 0 + 1)) + 0);
                o = t[index];

                // hour initialized
                o.hour = getTimer();

                // we insert this item in dataProvider
                ac.addItem(o);  

                if(aAdded.indexOf(o["a"]) == -1)
                {
                    aAdded.push(o["a"]);
                }
            }

            // Natural sort
            aAdded.sort();

            // update of order tab
            for(var s:String in aAdded)
            {
                if(order.indexOf(aAdded[s]) != -1)
                {
                    order.splice(order.indexOf(aAdded[s]), 1);
                }
                order.push(aAdded[s]);
            }

            // we update GroupingCollection2
            gc.refresh();
        }

        private function compare(o1:Object, o2:Object, fields:Array = null):int
        {
            // order in order tab...
            if(order.indexOf(o1.a) > order.indexOf(o2.a))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(order.indexOf(o1.a) < order.indexOf(o2.a))
            {
                return -1;
            }else
            {
                // ... then natural order on "b"...
                if(o1.b > o2.b)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if(o1.b < o2.b)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else{
                    // ... then numeric order on hour field
                    if(o1.hour > o2.hour)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if(o1.hour < o2.hour)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And that's work fine :)